# Kohana welcome page not shown xampp

Tags: kohana-3.2

My website path is
    c:\xamp\dhtdocs\egotist\kohana
    init \egotist\kohana\
    RewriteBase /egotist/kohana/
    RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
Welcome controller path C:\xampp\htdocs\egotist\kohana\application\classes\controller

Why when I load http://www.localhost:1337/egotist/kohana welcome controller not shown

spent 3 days on this

I cannot post with localhost, I have to add www

Comment: What is shown? Did you ever get to see install.php? Is the "d" in the first path is a typo? please give more info, and maybe format is better because I have a hard time figuring out what you mean.